# Bloqueando commit no git - opção lock

Tags: git, versionamento

Estou incumbido de implantar um sistema de versionamento aqui na empresa.
Contudo estou em dúvida entre o SVN e o Git.

Minha duvida é se o git possui algo que faça o mesmo que o `lock` do SVN, isto é, que bloqueie o `commit` de alguns determinados arquivos para determinado `branch`.

o que eu teria é '3 branchs' fixos:

- **Master:** onde fica a aplicação principal.
- **Homologação:** onde aguarda o cliente testar e homologar.
- **Teste:** onde o fica uma versão "final" da versão do programa, para teste intensivo pela equipes.

depois tem os de desenvolvimentos.

Contudo nesses 3 branchs, possuem alguns arquivos de configurações(como do banco de dados, do FTP, Etc) que não devem passar para o outro `branch`.
Então eu gostaria, para evitar erros humanos, bloquear o `merge`/`commit` desses arquivos entre os branchs e gostaria de saber se o git tem como fazer(ou teria algum outro que permite).

Comment: não sei se é a melhor solução, mas você pode utilizar um arquivo chamado .gitignore que previne arquivos ou pastas serem enviados pro Git

Comment: o problema eh que ai esses arquivos não iriam para o servidor/repositorio...

Comment: Olha, o lock do SVN, não é bem isso que você precisa. O lock do SVN é por usuário. Você "locka" o arquivo, para evitar que outra pessoa faça o commit antes de você, só isso. Oque você precisa, é trabalhar com o arquivo de permissões, e isso tem tanto no Git quanto no SVN. Se dá pra escolher, vai de Git.

Comment: Não to entendendo muito bem o seu caso de uso. Veja, se você bloquear o merge/commit de um arquivo versionado, como vai mandar ele pro servidor quando ele precisar de fato ser alterado? Manualmente. Agora, se vai copiar na mão sempre, pra que versionar junto com todo o resto, principalmente em se tratando de dados sensíveis? Mais fácil manter ignorado.

Comment: Victor tadashi, como fazemos isso? Tem os passos?

Comment: Ricardo, primeiramente pelo principal motivo de se versionar: ter versões/histórico do arquivo. Segundo seria somente alguns usuários que poderiam alterar esses arquivos por questão de responsabilidade e não correr o risco de commits engano

Answer (score 2):

Ignorando a parte de sua estrutura de *branchs* que pode ser uma discussão a parte, o que você está precisando é algo bem diferente da solução que está pensando. Você precisa de um processo de Continous Integration e Continous Deploy.

Por que digo isso? Primeiramente porque atualmente é crucial que seus Deploys sejam executados de maneira automatizada, eliminando possíveis erros operacionais, em segundo lugar, você tem variáveis que se alteram de acordo com o ambiente de implantação, e que são sensíveis, e não é qualquer um que pode ter acesso.

O que sugiro para você é utilizar uma Ferramenta como o Visual Studio Team Services (VSTS) para gerenciar seus projetos. Lá, além de ter um repositório GIT para controle de versão, você tem o processo de *build* automático e também o Deploy automático.

No processo de Deploy, você pode configurar seus ambientes como Dev, Homologação, produção, etc, e embutir nesses ambientes esses dados sensíveis de maneira criptografada, garantindo também a segurança em todo o processo.

Caso queira saber mais sobre o VSTS, assista [essa playlist](http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLMFPOLE2cW1wynLrJqkAyfvCxRKsOqX-w).